# git bash color linux

Tags: git, bash

Хочу добавить в баш отображение ветки гита, и выделения цвета,

```
parse_git_branch () { 
 git branch 2> / dev / null | sed -e '/ ^ [^ *] / d' -e 's / * \ (. * \) / (\ 1) /'} export PS1 = "\ u @ \ h \ [\ e [32m \] \ w \ [\ e [91m \] \ $ (parse_git_branch) \ [\ e [00m \] $" "
```

вывод получается вот таким `bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: строка 76: неожиданный конец файла во время поиска «"»
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: строка 78: синтаксическая ошибка: неожиданный конец файла`

как исправить? пробовал разные варианты, но так и не пришел к решению

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716445/1892060?

Comment: кавычек непарное количество

Answer (score -1, accepted):

в общем пришлось полностью переписать весь баш, взяв за исходник у этого парня https://github.com/slomkowski/bash-full-of-colors/blob/master/bashrc.sh

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]